# Can we use Where clause in WPF Binding in code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a scenario in which I want to create a Binding object in code behind and then hook this up to the datagrid column. Something like this:

```
int i = 5; // Will get this value from some other object

Binding b = new Binding("Customers.where(c => c.CustomerId == " + i + ").ToList()[0].OrderValue");  // how to make this work ?

telerikGridView.Columns.Add(
    new Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewDataColumn
        {
            Header = "Customer",
            DataMemberBinding = b
        }
    );
```

I saw another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627186/can-you-use-a-where-clause-in-wpf-xaml-binding) where it's suggested that I can use the converter or I should create a custom binding class. But converter isn't working either.

Am I missing some very trivial thing here ?

Comment: create a property with an observable collection which will hold "Customers.where(c => c.CustomerId == " + i + ").ToList()[0].OrderValue"); then bind it to the viewmodel which holds this property. use MVVM for WPF not code behind

Comment: Well, I can't do that actually. This is a part of the requirement in which I can add any number of the customers to the class which is a DataContext here.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't. if you want to share data between the classes give them a common interface.

Comment: So this Customer's collection actually holds the customers which I may keep on adding in the class (which is datacontext) and this number of customers which I can add is un-defined

Comment: Ok so notify/update the classes about the different number of elements which were added. have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: The problem is data grid here, some columns of the data grid are static, whereas I want to add some columns to the grid on requirement basis. So I will add a customer and the should show up in a new column. I hope this will make it more clear

Comment: you can still do that. create the right class for your viewmodel. the columns which are static init them in the ctor of the viewmodel and the rest of the you will add to the observable collection. this way you will have static columns and dynamic columns.

Comment: You could bind to collection and add converter to use Where clause in it. If it could help, please let me know and will discuss it

Comment: @VMaleev I tried to use the converter, but somehow the data grid cell is not editable after applying the converter, I am not able to figure that out why is that so.

Comment: Dat's correct, you won't be able to edit it because you will need to implement ConvertBack method. I've read your post once again and I suppose it would be better to implement correct ViewModel for you. Is ID filter configurable or hard-coded?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Observable collections on your class then create a property changed event then on that event manipulate your data(where clause) then bind it.

```
var coll = viewModel.GetPropertyValue("Customers") as ObservableCollection<Customers>;
coll += CustomerPropertychange_Event;
```